# VLC Player Problem?

Tags: ipad

recently i downloaded VLCP layer for my iPad2.

i know that VLC player can play MKV format.

so i add MKV format movie into my ipad2 and test it.

one warning occur "Your iPad2 is too slow to play that movie".

i think that iPad2's processor are dual.

so why its happening?

Can't i watch MKV format in my iPad2.

if it can be please tell me how to do that.

Thanks you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

(HD-)MKVs require a lot more processing power than the iPad can offer. Bear in mind that all the decoding in VLC for iOS is done in software...iOS devices only have H.264/MP4 hardware decoding support - and VLC is not using it, even for files in said format. If you want to watch HD files on your iPad, you need to reencode them to H.264 in a MP4 container and watch them using the iOS video player.